# Burnside's lemma: 30 possible different dice

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I have been working with Burnside's counting lemma and I came across the problem to show that there are 30 possible different dice.

I have tried working with the 24 rotational symmetries of the cube but can't get to an answer.  Any help please?

Comment: What do you mean by "different dice"

Comment: Why don't you write down the terms that you have so that we can check your computations? It could be just a calculation error.

Comment: I believe the question is meant to say that the numbers are in different positions relative to each other, i.e.: cannot be mapped into each other through the rotational symmetries of the cube.

Comment: And yes maybe you should edit your question to say "dice (cube with each of {1,2,3,4,5,6} on a unique face)" and you want to count "the number of different dice up to rotation".

Comment: Dp you mean that the faces of the cube are to be numbered, each of the numbers from $1$ to $6$ being used once? Does the orientation of a number make a difference? E.g., if you use patterns of dots as on ordinary dice, note that the patters for $2$, $3$, and $6$ dots are asymmetric.

Comment: The question does not specify any of these parameters

Comment: @bof thanks for clearing the matter, I was finding the use of Burnside's Lemma trivial because of the invariance of all the colourings. Thanks!

Comment: @bof, well done.

Comment: @bof Why not post your comment as an answer? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The answer "$30$" tells me that the orientation of the number on a face of the die doesn't make a difference. In that case, a clearer way to state the problem would be, you have $6$ different colors of paint, how many distinguishable ways can you paint each face of the cube a different color? With this restriction, there are no invariant colorings for any of the rotations except the identity, so Burnside's lemma gives$$\frac{6!+0+0+\cdots+0}{24}=30.$$Of course there are many other ways to arrive at this answer. For example, we can arbitrarily start by painting the bottom red. There are then $5$ choices of color for the top, and $3!$ cyclic orderings for the other $4$ colors, so again we get the answer $5\cdot3!=30$.

If, instead of coloring the faces of the cube, you number them from $1$ to $6$, with the numbers represented by patterns of spots as on an ordinary gambling cube, and if you take into account the fact that the patterns of two, three, or six spots can be oriented in two different ways, the number of different dice is then $2^3*30=240$.